# Not all classes are exported by CSV Module in API O MAT

Tags: mobile, backend

I'm building my mobile backend with [apiomat](http://apiomat.com). Now i added the CSV module to export my data. But there are not all classes included. What's going wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you did not redeploy after changing your data models. Just go to the deploy screen and hit deploy on either productive or test.

Also, please pay attention for which of both systems are exporting data; you can switch with the slider on the left menu.

You may also take a look at the [API O MAT Wiki](http://wiki.apiomat.com)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Thank you for your fast repsponse